# How to create a Plone form widget that works like MultiContentTreeFieldWidget but preserves the order of items

Tags: forms, plone, zope, dexterity

I have a dexterity behaviour that allows me to relate items and store the relations as UUIDs

```python
relatedItems = schema.List(
            title=u"Related Items",
            description=u"Search for content that is related to this item",
            required=False,
            value_type=schema.Choice(
                source=UUIDSourceBinder(navigation_tree_query={'portal_type':
                   TYPES_WITH_TEASERS})))
form.widget(relatedItems='plone.formwidget.contenttree.widget.MultiContentTreeFieldWidget')
```

This works great except that if you have a few relations then every time you edit the item their order changes.  We're displaying the related items in the right hand column of the page (e.g. see this [article about food](http://www.our-africa.org/foods)) and want to control the order so that we can put more interesting teasers first.

Debugging it looks likely this reordering is down to the fact `z3c.formwidget.query.widget.QuerySourceRadioWidget.update` uses a set when processing request parameters.  Presumably this is to prevent duplicates but has two nasty side effects:

1. a field’s value gets updated when it hasn't changed
2. order is lost when it might be important

Is there an alternative to `MultiContentTreeFieldWidget` that works in a similar way but preserves the order you add items?  Even better is there a widget that does this and also allows you to reorder items as well?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not have an answer for you. I just wanted to say: what a wonderful site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find an alternative but subsequently z3c.formwidget.query has been updated to use a list instead of a set when processing request parameters.  Version 0.7 fixes this

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.formwidget.query/0.7

Add the following to your [versions] section in buildout to resolve

```
z3c.formwidget.query = 0.7
```